# Mandar notificación push en android desde la propia app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, notificaciones

Estoy haciendo pruebas en una app y quiero que al pulsar un botón se mande una notificación push que aparezca en la parte superior de la pantalla y se quede en el centro de notificaciones. Hasta ahora tengo este código y al pulsar el botón sí que hace un sonido pero no muestra notificación ni hace nada.

Código en el main:

```
Button notificationButton = findViewById(R.id.pruebaNotification);
        notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });
```

Clases:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "My Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel");
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacion)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("This is a local notification.")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
```

No encuentro que es lo que tengo mal o que debería añadir.

---

En mi archivo manifest tengo puestos los siguientes permisos:

```
<!--Permiso para poder usar notificaciones-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NOTIFICATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Verifica que versión de android tienes, recuerda que apartir de la versión 13 es necesario pedir permiso de la notificación Te dejo [link de la documentación](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra en esta línea:

```
 notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

**estás definiendo en tu método [notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) la misma id para tus notificaciones ( 1 ), esto provocará que la misma notificación se esté reemplazando, y que no se genere una nueva**. Te sugiero definir un id diferente para cada notificación.

Por ejemplo, puedes crear una variable que se esté incrementando, esto para definir un id diferente para cada notificación.

```
private int idNotificacion = 0;

private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacion)
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setContentText("This is a local notification.")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(idNotification++, builder.build());
}
```